# Shapeless: flatMap over tuple fails to compile

Tags: scala, shapeless

Using shapeless and an example from the tutorial:

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.std.tuple._
import poly._

object ShapelessPlay extends App{

  val t = ((1,"a"),'c')

  println(t flatMap identity)
}
```

I get the following error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter mapper: shapeless.ops.tuple.FlatMapper[((Int, String), Char),shapeless.poly.identity.type]
```

println(t flatMap identity)

What am I missing?
            ^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It fails because `flatMap` expects its function argument to yield a tuple (of some arity or other) when applied to each of the elements of its left hand side. `identity` yields a tuple when applied to `(1, "a")`, but not when applied to `'c'` ... in the latter case it yields a `Char`. What you really want here is,

```
scala> ((1, "a"), Tuple1('c')) flatMap identity
res0: (Int, String, Char) = (1,a,c)
```

which admittedly isn't quite as pretty as it should be because Scala doesn't have syntax for `Tuple1`.

Alternatively, it you simple want to append a value to a tuple, increasing the latter's arity by one, the simplest option is to use `:+`,

```
scala> (1, "a") :+ 'c'
res0: (Int, String, Char) = (1,a,c)
```

Comment: It might be worth adding this as an example to the feature overview, since this is one of the most common flatten scenarios

Comment: I've updated the answer with a simpler way of appending a single value to a tuple ... is this what you had in mind?

Comment: My common use case in scalding is having to flatten stuff like ((a,b),c), which I usually do naively {case ((a,b),c) => (a,b,c)}. I'm trying to get a .flatten method working.

Comment: A flatten operation which behaves the way you want is certainly possible, but it isn't the same as flatMap identity. See the example [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/flatten.scala).